# Filtering ArrayAdapter ListView with Image

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm having problem to filter my listview and can't find any good example for my situation. Actually my listview is list of my facebook friend together with the image. My class is an activity that implement the text watcher and below is my code .

```
    public ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = null;

    friendFilter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.friends_filter);
    friendList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.fb_friend_list);                      

    friendList.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    friendFilter.addTextChangedListener(this);

    adapter = new FbFriendListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),nameIDPath, friendName);
    friendList.setAdapter(adapter);
    friendList.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

textwatcher ontextchanged,

```
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        Log.d("adapter count", "adapter count " + adapter.getCount());
        adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
    }
```

My Adapter

```
public class FbFriendListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    public static FriendsGetProfilePics model;
    private ArrayList<String> nameIDPath;
    private Context context;
    Bitmap icon;
    Hashtable<Integer, Bitmap> friendsImages;

    public FbFriendListAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<String> nameIDPath, List<String> friendName){
        super(c, R.layout.fb_friend_adapter, friendName);
        this.nameIDPath = nameIDPath;
        this.context = c;
        if(model==null){
        model = new FriendsGetProfilePics();
        }
        model.setListener(this);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return nameIDPath.size();       
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    static class ViewHolder{
        public TextView descHolder;
        public ImageView typeHolder;
    }   

    public View getView(int position, View convertview, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder vh;
        vh = new ViewHolder();
        if(convertview==null){          
            LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertview = inf.inflate(R.layout.fb_friend_adapter, null,true);

            vh.descHolder = (TextView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.fbFriendName);             
            vh.typeHolder = (ImageView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.fbImage);                                                                     
            convertview.setTag(vh);             
        }else{
            vh = (ViewHolder)convertview.getTag();
        }           

        String[] names = nameIDPath.get(position).toString().split("@NAMES");
        String[] idpath = names[1].toString().split("@PATH");
        vh.descHolder.setText(names[0]);
        vh.typeHolder.setImageBitmap(model.getImage(idpath[0],idpath[1]));      
        return convertview;
    }   
}
```

Please guide me.

Comment: I found the solution, actually in the adapter class I do not need to override getCount. Method getCount in my cases return the size of ArrayList. So the filter seems not working.